# Name of a Sci-Fi book about 'realist and vicarious life styles'

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm struggling to remember the title of a science fiction book I read 40-50 years ago.

The book featured people living realist and vicarious lifestyles, known as "Rees" and "Vikes".

Comment: What are the "rees and vickies" you reference? Do you remember anything about the characters, settings, or any details about the plot? Was it in English? Did it seem to be aimed at any particular audience or age group?

Comment: I remember reading the short story in a SF collection. I despaired of ever finding it again. It's where I picked up saying "scroom".

Answer (score 5):

The book you're looking for is "[Tomorrow and Tomorrow](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1944861.Tomorrow_and_Tomorrow)" by Hunt Collins

[image: Tomorrow and Tomorrow Book cover]

the NY Times review (from 1956) describes the book thusly;

> A casual observer of today's newsstands, beaches, TV and movie screens
>   might well agree with Hunt Collins' hypothesis that we are moving
>   toward a world of wholly vicarious living. In as neat a bit of science
>   fiction as I've seen this year, he has pictured a world peopled
>   largely by **Vikes (for Vicarions)** wherein drug addiction is
>   respectable, feminine streetwear makes our own Bikini bathing suit
>   look like the missionary's Mother Hubbard, and pornography is standard
>   fare. Conversely, and reasonably, physical contact between Vikes is
>   tabu- even eating is a revolting procedure, to be carried out in utter
>   solitude. Opposed to the Vikes are the minority **Rees (for Realists)**
>   who have gone to the other extreme and are a dreary lot.
>
> The struggle between these faction is marked by pleasingly intricate
>   chicanery. The book is flawed by a dreadfully trite conclusion and the
>   technological background is not as complete as it might be. These
>   weaknesses aside, it is a fine, realistic novel of a not impossible
>   future.

Comment: Wow... finally a SFF book where scantily-clad woman on the cover actually **is on-topic**!